# How do I set a command to be another command powershell?

Tags: git, powershell

I want to just set 1 word that if i type it will be equivalent to git push origin master on powershell. I tried looking it up online but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Open powershell and declare a function:

```
function my_function{git push origin master}
```

Then call the function

```
my_function
```

That's all